# Download active datatable of tabpanel in shiny

Tags: r, list, datatable, shiny, tabpanel

I am a new shiny user,and I have some problems creating my own shiny apps.Here are trimmed down code snippet for illustration of my current approach.

```
#ui.r
shinyUI(fluidPage(
sidebarLayout(
mainPanel(
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel(
      selectInput("HM", "hour means",
                  c("A" = 1,
                    "B" = 2,
                    "C" = 3,
                    )),
      dataTableOutput('HOUR_MEAN')
    ),
    tabPanel(
      selectInput("DM", "day means",
                  c("A" = 1,
                    "B" = 2,
                    "C" = 3,
                    )),
      dataTableOutput('DAY_MEAN')
    )
  )))))
###server.r
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$HOUR_MEAN<-renderDataTable({
  L<-myfun(mydata)
  a<-input$HM
  L[[1]][[eval(parse(text=a))]]
  })

  output$DAY_MEAN<-renderDataTable({
  L<-myfun2(mydata)
  a<-input$DM
  L[[2]][[eval(parse(text=a))]]
  })

  })
```

Now what I want is to download the datatable when I choose the different panel and the different selections of the tabpanel?
Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

try this

ui part

```
fluidRow(  downloadButton('download_hour', 'download data'))) # in a tabitem
```

server part

```
 output$download_hour = downloadHandler('mydataoutput.csv', content =    function(file) {
s = input$HOUR_MEAN_rows_all  
write.table(mydata[s, ], file  ,sep=";",row.names = F)
 })
```